# Segmented table

Tags: tables

[image]

Can I do this kind of table in LaTeX?

---

I'd like to apply the answers to this table:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1.5cm,top=1cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
text & text & text \\ 
\hline
text & text & text \\ 
\hline
text & text & text \\ 
\hline
text & text & text \\ 
\hline
text & text & text \\ 
\hline
text & text & text \\ 
\hline
text & text & text \\ 
\hline
text & text & text \\ 
\hline
text & text & text \\ 
\hline
text & text & text \\ 
\hline
text & text & text \\ 
\hline
text & text & text \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks more like a picture than a table.

Comment: Actually it's a picture, but since I couldn't produce it in LaTeX, I had to draw it first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Feeling that it is more like a picture, I coded it in `TikZ`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tp/.style={minimum height=6cm+2\pgflinewidth,minimum width=1cm,fill=white},line width=1pt]

\node[minimum size=6cm,inner sep=0pt,draw] (big) {};
\draw (big.180)--(big.0)(big.90)--(big.-90);

\node[tp] at ($(big.center)!.5!(big.0)$) {};
\node[tp] at ($(big.center)!.5!(big.180)$) {};
\node[tp,rotate=90] at ($(big.center)!.5!(big.90)$) {};
\node[tp,rotate=90] at ($(big.center)!.5!(big.-90)$) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Also, adding text cannot be more easier!

[image]

See this example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[BL/.style={draw=blue,line width=1cm,shorten >=-1pt,shorten <=-1pt},line width=1pt]

\node[minimum size=6cm,inner sep=0pt,draw] (big) {};
\draw (big.180)--(big.0)(big.90)--(big.-90);

\draw[BL]($(big.90)!.5!(big.135)$)--($(big.-90)!.5!(big.-135)$);
\draw[BL]($(big.90)!.5!(big.45)$)--($(big.-90)!.5!(big.-45)$);    
\draw[BL]($(big.180)!.5!(big.135)$)--node[pos=.25,fill=white]{Cell no. 11}node[pos=.75,fill=white]{Cell no. 12}($(big.0)!.5!(big.45)$);
\draw[BL]($(big.180)!.5!(big.-135)$)--node[pos=.25,fill=white]{Cell no. 21}node[pos=.75,fill=white]{Cell no. 22}($(big.0)!.5!(big.-45)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Update**

As for the final edited version of the question, here is another `TikZ` implementation which accepts any table size:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,colortbl}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mytable}[1]{\ifnum#1>0\hline\else\fi
text & text & text \\ \ifnum#1>0\hline\else\fi
text & text & text \\ \ifnum#1>0\hline\else\fi
text & text & text \\ \ifnum#1>0\hline\else\fi
text & text & text \\ \ifnum#1>0\hline\else\fi
text & text & text \\ \ifnum#1>0\hline\else\fi
text & text & text \\ \ifnum#1>0\hline\else\fi
text & text & text \\ \ifnum#1>0\hline\else\fi
text & text & text \\ \ifnum#1>0\hline\else\fi
text & text & text \\ \ifnum#1>0\hline\else\fi
text & text & text \\ \ifnum#1>0\hline\else\fi
text & text & text \\ \ifnum#1>0\hline\else\fi
text & text & text \\ \ifnum#1>0\hline\else\fi
}
\newcolumntype{W}{>{\color{white}}l}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=-1pt,shorten <=-1pt]
\node[draw,inner sep=0pt](table){%
\begin{tabular}{|W|W|W|}
\mytable{1}
\end{tabular}};

\foreach \x in {1,3,5}
\draw[white,line width=.3cm] ($(table.north west)!\x/6!(table.north east)$)--($(table.south west)!\x/6!(table.south east)$);
\foreach \x in {1,3,...,23}
\draw[white,line width=.1cm] ($(table.north west)!\x/24!(table.south west)$)--($(table.north east)!\x/24!(table.south east)$);

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{.4pt}
\node at (table.center){\noindent%
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\mytable{0}
\end{tabular}};    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The first `\foreach` loops over odd numbers from `1` to `2*#columns-1` and the second `\foreach` loops over odd numbers from `1` to `2*#rows-1`. Also, `\x/6` are multiples of a half-column width and `\x/24` are multiples of a half-row height. Table rows are entered in the `\mytable` command only once.

Comment: @Oshnaj Please see my updated answer.

Comment: God, it's way too complex. It looks beautiful though.

Answer (score 3):

Here I make my own macro `\Dcell[]`, which is to be used as a component of a TABstack, to create the table.  I admit the possibility of adding text to the elements with the optional argument to `\Dcell`.  There are 3 user parameters at the top of the file:

`\rlwd` the width of the corner rules

`\rlln` the length of the corner rules

`\cellhgap` the empty gap between the two corner rules (the vertical gap auto-adjusts to keep the cell square.

Obviously, `\cellhgap + 2\rlln` must exceed the widest text entry.

While there is a bit of preamble setup, the actual usage is quite trivial.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\def\rlwd{.4pt}
\def\rlln{3ex}
\def\cellhgap{3ex}
\def\cellfield{\dimexpr\cellhgap + 2\dimexpr\rlln}
\def\cellvgap{.5\dimexpr\cellhgap-\ht\strutbox\relax}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\setstackgap{S}{-\rlwd}
\fixTABwidth{T}
\newcommand\Dcell[1][]{\protect\Dcellraw{#1}}
\newcommand\Dcellraw[1]{%
 \stackunder[\cellvgap]{%
  \stackon[\cellvgap]{\makebox[\cellfield]{\strut#1}}{%
    \rule[\dimexpr-\rlln+\rlwd\relax]{\rlwd}{\rlln}\rule{\rlln}{\rlwd}%
    \hspace{\cellhgap}%
    \rule{\rlln}{\rlwd}\rule[\dimexpr-\rlln+\rlwd\relax]{\rlwd}{\rlln}}%
 }{%
    \rule{\rlwd}{\rlln}\rule{\rlln}{\rlwd}%
    \hspace{\cellhgap}%
    \rule{\rlln}{\rlwd}\rule{\rlwd}{\rlln}%
 }\kern-\dimexpr\rlwd%
}
\begin{document}
\tabbedShortstack{
  \Dcell[xyz]&\Dcell\cr
  \Dcell[z]&\Dcell[abcdefg]
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Oshnaj It seems that either of the two current answers can accomplish what you ask.